# Extra alignment tab error, on Table

Tags: tables, align, tabularx

I am trying to make a table in LaTeX. However, I get several *extra alignment tab* errors and I do not know why.

I have searched here for similar problems but I only found [extra alignment tab error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/extra-alignment-tab-error)
and that is a different problem cause by the `%`, which I do not use.
So, I am quite lost, at the moment.

Here is some minimal code that reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

%define some nice colors
\definecolor{middleware_green}{RGB}{82, 119, 17}
\definecolor{middleware_white}{RGB}{255, 255, 255}
\definecolor{middleware_light_gray}{RGB}{239, 239, 239}
\definecolor{middleware_dark_gray}{RGB}{153, 153, 153}

%renewing commands for tabularx
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}

%new column type for test tables 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\raggedleft\arraybackslash\sffamily}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\centering\arraybackslash\sffamily}X}%

\newcolumntype{R}{|>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\color{magenta!70!black}\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize}p{2.5cm}}%
\newcolumntype{H}{|>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\color{orange!30!black}\centering\arraybackslash\sffamily\footnotesize}X}%
\newcolumntype{J}{|>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\color{green!30!black}\centering\sffamily\footnotesize}X}%
\newcolumntype{W}{|>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\color{blue!30!black}\centering\arraybackslash\sffamily\footnotesize}X|}%


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ph!]
\footnotesize\centering
\rowcolors{2}{middleware_white}{middleware_light_gray}

\begin{tabularx}{0.46\textwidth}{|L|L|L|L|L|}
\hline\rowcolor{middleware_green}
\multicolumn{ 5}{|c|}{\small\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Cloud Types}}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor{middleware_dark_gray}
\multicolumn{1}{|C}{\scriptsize\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Pu\-blic cloud}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|C}{\scriptsize\centering\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Pri\-va\-te cloud}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|C}{\scriptsize\centering\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Hy\-brid cloud}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|C|}{\scriptsize\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Vir\-tu\-al pri\-va\-te cloud}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|C|}{\scriptsize\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Com\-mu\-ni\-ty cloud}}} & \\ \hline
Definition  &   Public cloud definition &   Private cloud definition    &   Hybrid cloud defitnion  &   Virtual Private Cloud definition    &   Community Cloud definition  \\ \hline
Advantages  &   Public cloud advantages &   Private cloud advantages    &   Hybrid cloud advantages &   Virtual Private Cloud advantages    &   Community Cloud advantages  \\ \hline
Disadvantages   &   Public cloud disadvantages  &   Private cloud disadvantages &   Hybrid cloud disadvantages  &   Virtual Private Cloud disadvantages &   Community Cloud disadvantages   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Cloud Types\label{tab:cloud_types}}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Column types `L` and `C` are not defined and there is also a missing `&` after the second last `\multicolumn{1}{|C|}{...}`.

Comment: Ok, I updated the document, but I still cant get rid of the problem !

Comment: Now you have defined five columns for your table, but as @dcmst said, the row starting with `Definition &` has *six* columns, as do the next two rows. Edit: Remember that `&` separates columns, so if there are five `&` in a row, that means there are six columns.

Answer (score 2):

The `tabular` content is divided into six columns, but only five are declared with the macro.

Something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{|L|L|L|L|L|}         %five columns
                 1&2&3&4&5&6         %six columns
\end{tabular}
```

Which will not work.

To solve the compilation error the number of columns should be equal or less than that declared with the macro.